# Chrome extension - options page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to write a basic options page to my extension. I tried the basic example here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2 , but it seems not work - I do get the options page, but when I click on save, nothing happens, and also when closing and opening the options page - my settings are lost. I copied exactly the two files options.html and options.js into my basic extension (in developer mode of course - unpacked extension).
Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, seems like I didn't google enough before posting - I was missing the "storage" permission in my manifest. Can be closed.